# How to update random rows in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

I have a SQLite database. I'm trying to update the values of random rows.

To select `n` random rows I use:

```
SELECT col1 FROM table ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT n;
```

However, I can't manage to update values in the same way. Using

```
UPDATE table SET col1="foo" ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT n;
```

yields an error

```
Error: near "ORDER": syntax error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SELECT` and `UPDATE` together:

```
UPDATE ... WHERE table.col1 IN (SELECT col1 ...);
```

So, using your command to select random rows, you can update those rows with

```
UPDATE table
SET col1="foo"
WHERE table.col1
IN
    (
    SELECT col1
    FROM table
    ORDER BY RANDOM()
    LIMIT n
    );
```

A more concise way, though less flexible:

```
UPDATE table SET col1="foo" WHERE RANDOM()%10=0;
```

This will randomly select a tenth of the rows. You can adjust the modulo to get more or less rows, etc.